# Receiving error for the Context does not exist for datatable

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, datatable

I am creating a datatable (below is my method). Am I missing anything due to which I am receiving error that

> The name 'Context' does not exist in the current context

```
 public void GetEmployees()
        {
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetEmployees", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Employee employee = new Employee();
                    employee.Id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Id"]);
                    employee.FirstName = rdr["FirstName"].ToString();
                    employee.LastName = rdr["LastName"].ToString();
                    employee.Gender = rdr["Gender"].ToString();
                    employee.JobTitle = rdr["JobTitle"].ToString();
                    employee.WebSite = rdr["WebSite"].ToString();
                    employee.Salary = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Salary"]);
                    employee.HireDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["HireDate"]);
                    employees.Add(employee);
                }
            }
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(employees));
        }
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Where is this code located?

Comment: in my Controller.cs file

Comment: When does the error occur?  During a test or when running the app in a browser?

Comment: When I build my app. The error is displayed in my error list.

Comment: Have you declared `Context` anywhere?  Did you mean `HttpContext`?

Comment: I am trying to do what this [link](http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2015/08/jquery-datatables-get-data-from.html) provided but I have changed my GetEmployees() based on my requirement but haven't posted same as it might confuse you all. But that is similar to what it is in mentioned link.

Comment: You are looking for `HttpContext` ... `WebService` has a `Context` property that points to the current `HttpContext` but in a `Controller` the related property is `HttpContext`.

Comment: So if I change `Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(employees));` to `HttpContext.Response.Write(js.Serialize(employees));` what should work?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a json string, you can use `Content` method in MVC

```
public ActionResult GetEmployees()
        {
            ...
            return Content(js.Serialize(employees), "application/json"); 
        }
```